# How to test translations on my android phone

Tags: android, localization

I have a problem with testing the japanese translations of my app, cause I can't switch my phone to japanese language: When I go to the phone's settings there is just no "japanese" entry in the list of languages. There are some entries which look like japanes, but I tried them and they dont show my translations, so I guess its not japanese...

Anyone knows how to test it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this in you languages: [wiki Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language) (日本語)as usualy name of the language is writen in it's language. In practice Japanese should be last one. If it is nor working(as some phones might not support this language) try on emulator.

Comment: Unfortunately my phone has no japanese language installed. However, I am accepting the answer due to the reccomendation of using the emultor.

Comment: hang on: I just found out that my emulator also doesnt have hindi or chinese installed... what can I do?